# Access AWS Credentials with AWS SAM Local (Python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-sam

I am trying to use SAM Local to test my lambda function (Python). My function requires access to S3, this is achieved through boto3. On my local machine my credentials are stored in `~/.aws/credentials` and from the SAM documentation it sounds like those credentials are accessed when using the SAM CLI

> SAM CLI will invoke functions with your locally configured IAM credentials.

This is how I access the S3 bucket when deployed on AWS:

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(<bucket_name>)
s3_bucket.download_file(<file_key>, 
<download_name>)
```

I have tried that way with SAM local invoke, but understand that you need to pass the AWS profile that you are using. So I tried to run this command:

```
sam local invoke <sam_identified> --event event.json --profile <aws_profile>
```

This never executes the function...it just hangs with this output `inside runtime container`

I have also tried:

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name=<aws_profile>)
s3_resource = Session.client('s3')
s3_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(<bucket_name>)
s3_bucket.download_file(<file_key>, 
<download_name>)
```

But when I run the command:

```
sam local invoke <sam_identified> --event event.json --profile <aws_profile>
```

I get this response:

```
The config profile (<aws_profile>) could not be found
```

I know there is no issue with my credentials located in `~/.aws/credentials` but feel like I may be missing something with how to access them through the SAM CLI. Any help with resolving this issue would be appreciated!

Comment: When asking questions, don't mask things that are not sensitive data. Makes it hard to read what you really have configured. The default profile in AWS is 'default'. Normally if you do not specify the profile name, then 'default' will be used. in your case use "--profile default" or whatever name you put in your credentials file.

Comment: Did you try using an aws default profile? might do things simpler for a start. Try naming your profile in aws creds file as `[default]` and not passing that flag to `sam`. Then, don't set the `Session` with a `profile_name`.

Comment: Any luck all these years later!?